# Email sent using hMailserver goes to spam

Tags: email, email-server, spam, hmailserver

I have configured hMailserver to send and receive email. It is working fine but all the mails sent to any address goes to spam.

Reverse PTR for my domain is ponting to my static IP.

mx-record is pointed to mail.mydomain.com

mail.mydomain.com points to my static ip but mydomain.com is hosted to a different shared hosting server.

Here is email header.

```
Delivered-To: destemail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.14.29.11 with SMTP id h11cs175274eea;
        Sun, 30 Jan 2011 23:07:22 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.142.231.17 with SMTP id d17mr5682675wfh.270.1296457641030;
        Sun, 30 Jan 2011 23:07:21 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <sourcemail@mydomain.com>
Received: from mail.mymydomain.com ([xxx.xxx.163.233])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id w5si48162450wfd.1.2011.01.30.23.07.18;
        Sun, 30 Jan 2011 23:07:20 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: xxx.xxx.163.233 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of sourcemail@mydomain.com) client-ip=xxx.xxx.163.233;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: xxx.xxx.163.233 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of sourcemail@mydomain.com) smtp.mail=sourcemail@mydomain.com
Received: from developer230 ([192.20.1.230])
 by mail.mydomain.com
 ; Mon, 31 Jan 2011 12:37:27 -0800
From: <sourcemail@mydomain.com>
To: <destemail@gmail.com>,
 <destemail@gmail.com>
Subject: test
```

What am I missing?

1. Figure out why my emails are directed to spam folder? (I have checked my IP is not listed in spam.)
2. Why the line in original header 
   **Received: from developer230 ([192.20.1.230])**

This IP is a local IP of my LAN. Why is hMailserver disclosing my local IP and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

to 1) Without seeing the mail it is impossible to say. Same goes with the obfuscated IP. Your mail could have spammy content or originate from a spammy IP.
The missing full name in the From: and To: headers for example. No Date: and no Message-ID: are only two more things. Not to mention the missing Content-Type: and the doubled recipient. So I would categorize the above mail as a junk mail. And Google is even more strict on that.

to 2) This is necessary by default. This is required by RFC 2821 Chapter 3.8.2 and RFC 2822 Chapter 3.6.7. You are not allowed to omit them.